# All house numbers in given zip and street

Tags: overpass-api

I'm a very beginner with overpass. I need to get all possible house numbers in area with given zip and a part of street.

For example.
All houses for: `10178 alex`

The result should be or similar to:

```
Alex-Wedding-Straße, 10178 Berlin
Tunnel Alexanderplatz, 10178 Berlin
Alexanderplatz, 10178 Berlin
Alexanderplatz 1, 10178 Berlin
Kleine Alexanderstraße 1, 10178 Berlin
Alexanderstraße 1, 10178 Berlin
Alexanderplatz 2, 10178 Berlin
```

I tried the next query, but it returned no results.

```
area[postal_code=10178][boundary=postal_code]->.a;
way(area.a)["highway"~"^(primary|secondary|tertiary|residential|living_street)$"]["name"~"^alex.*"]->.street;
(
  node["addr:housenumber"](area.street);
  way["addr:housenumber"](area.street);
  relation["addr:housenumber"](area.street);
);
(._;>;);out;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a guess: Overpass might not consider a street/way a valid area to search in, or at least not big enough (just a very thin line?). You could probably filter by housenumber and streetname `node["addr:housenumber"]["addr.street"~~"^alex.*"]`, depending on the OSM data that's available

Comment: "with given zip and a part of street" - so you want all addresses that match both your zip code and the street name?

Comment: @Mateusz Konieczny exactly!

Comment: "way(area.a)["highway"" was not working as expected as streets have no area. There is "around" but that would also fail as it would catch addresses of nearby streets or not catch some addresses far away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query assumes that

- you want all addresses that match both your zip code and specified part of the street name
- case insensitivity is preferred (alex filter should match also Alex, AleX etc)
- postal_code tag is tagged on area with boundary=postal_code (AFAIK not true everywhere)
- address is using addr:street and addr:housenumber tags

```
    area[postal_code=10178][boundary=postal_code]->.code;
    (
      node["addr:housenumber"]["addr:street"~"alex",i](area.code);
      way["addr:housenumber"]["addr:street"~"alex",i](area.code);
      relation["addr:housenumber"]["addr:street"~"alex",i](area.code);
    );
    (._;>;);out;
```

Comment: Im trying to get something similar to this to work on american streets but it doesn't seem to, do you have an example?

Comment: @MichaelLWatson Please link to a new question that demonstrates what is not working and what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Building on reducing activity's answer, the `area[postal_code=...]` filter appears to work mostly for just European locations. For US addresses, you can use bounding box to extract nodes within your Overpass Turbo viewport. Note that not all houses are marked with housenumber, and not all locations have this data, so please check your results.

1. Pan the window to an area of interest, or for this example enter the following coordinates into the oval search box on the top-right:

> 37.579304 -122.35901

2. Preview the selected buildings:

```
[out:json][timeout:250];
(
  node["addr:housenumber"]["addr:street"~"Walnut",i]({{bbox}});
  way["addr:housenumber"]["addr:street"~"Walnut",i]({{bbox}});
  relation["addr:housenumber"]["addr:street"~"Walnut",i]({{bbox}});
);
(._;>;);out;
```

[image: Preview Street Query using Map View]

Then you can export the selected houses in CSV format:

```
[out:csv('addr:housenumber','addr:street';',')][timeout:250];
(
  node["addr:housenumber"]["addr:street"~"Walnut",i]({{bbox}});
  way["addr:housenumber"]["addr:street"~"Walnut",i]({{bbox}});
  relation["addr:housenumber"]["addr:street"~"Walnut",i]({{bbox}});
);
out;
```

[image: Export addresses as CSV in data view]